# Convert varchar to date MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date, time

I have a varchar in this format: Thu Jun 14 22:20:40 +0000 2012
how can I change the entire column in a table in MYSQL (called "date") to datetime format from varchar automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`STR_TO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to get the data in the right format

```
UPDATE `date`
SET `date` = STR_TO_DATE(`date`,'%a %b %H:%i:%s +0000 %Y')
```

Then alter your table:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER COLUMN `date` DATETIME NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

This should be helpful, just make mask according to your date format